# How to find a source?

Tags: regression, machine-learning-model, preprocessing

I am given a dataset where I have to predict the distance. The training dataset consists of the values of the signal strength of 5 different sensors and the distance between the source and the 4
points where those 5 sensors are placed.

Example

[image]

Based on this kind of training dataset, I have to predict distance for a particular vector of **signal strength**. Here D1,  D2 are numerical values.

Can one guide which regressor model and what preprocessing technique will be useful here?

I am new to the ML domain!

Comment: From the table it looks like the 'distance' is not numerical but categorical: D1, D2,D3, D4. If so this is not regression but classification. Additionally does your dataset have only 4 instances? If yes this is way too small for proper statistical learning. You could just calculate a distance with D1, D2, D3,D4 based on the features (sensors) and then pick the min. It would be equivalent to using kNN with k=1.

Comment: @Erwan D's are numerical, I have mentioned. This example here is just a sample. There are all total 1000+ such instances.

Comment: So all the Ds are different, they don't correspond to a fixed set of locations as indicated in this table?

Comment: D1 is the distance between P1 and Source; D1 = EucliD(Source,P1). Rest are also same!

Comment: If the locations are all different with each other, then you're correct that this is a regression task. You have many choices, I often recommend decision trees or SVM regression. Are the values of the sensors normalized? The ones in the table look like [0-100], but if not they should be scaled for SVM.

Comment: Thanks! I will let you know once I fit the model!